A police agent is sent to prison to expose a gang, and then he finds himself in danger
When did you read the story/poem/novel, etc., and how old was it?
I read it about 5-9 years ago, so somewhere between 2015 and 2019. I'm not sure when the book was first published but I suppose that it was about max. 5 years earlier.
Medium and appearance
It was a book, rather long, approx. 400-500 pages. Black-and-white, I don't think that there were any photos or artworks.
What language did you read it in, and was it translated?
The book was in Polish, but it was translated. Most certainly from Swedish or Norwegian.
Where did you read this story?
I borrowed this book from a local library.
What age range was this story for?
I would say for a person starting from 14 yo.
Anything else
It was of thriller or criminal genre. As far as I can tell the story was set up in contemporary Sweden or Norway, certainly a Nordic/Scandinavian setting. A male police agent (who had female pseudonim - I remember that it was something typical) was sent to prison to uncover a gang (perhaps . Before he was sent to prison he did some preparations. One of which was to hide a small gun in a book. That book was to somehow find its way to the prison. As far as I remember he demanded this book to be bought by a prison's library. The true identity of the agent was somehow revealed and inmates tried to kill him. As far as I can tell he managed to avoid being killed.
